# Compute the Poisson kernel for a quadrant of the plane

Tags: analysis

I have the following problem:

> Compute the Poisson kernel for a quadrant of the plane.

I don't know how to start, I don't even know what is the Green function of a quadrant of the plane. Can you help me please?

Comment: I bet you should use the method of reflections.

Comment: The text does not provide any hint except for this: refine the method of images illustrated for the half plane (and the method of reflections wasn't mentioned anywhere)

Comment: What I called “method of reflections” is exactly the “method of images” your text mentions. You will surely find an explanation of this method for the cases of the half-plane and of the circle. The task is to adapt this method to the case of the quadrant.